# Scope for events inside tab

Tags: javascript, polymer

Dears,

By subscribing (dispatchEvent/addEventListener) to "window." or "document.body." I see events fired from the different tabs (or windows). How can I reduce scope to the current tab/window only?

From the app module 1:

```
  __handleResponse(msg) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('status-update', {'detail': msg}));
  }
```

From the app module 2:

```
  ready() {
    super.ready();

    window.addEventListener('status-update', e => this._statusUpdateEvent(e));

  }
```

window.addEventListener from all tabs captures events from dispatchEvent at any brwoser's tab

Comment: In what browser do you see this mysterious, highly doubtfull behavior?

Comment: This appears in Chrome. Not able to test in FF unfortunately

Comment: Uhm well besides myself I'm sure there are a few other people who would love to see a demonstration of this. Please post some code showing this behavior. Until then I don't think I can help you solve this as I personally have never seen this happen.

Comment: On my Chrome and FF it works as expected. Try your example outside of the project.